# How to get count of unique values in all individual columns of a groupby result in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Pandas dataframe and want to get unique values count in individual columns of the output of groupby on 2 columns of the dataframe.

My input dataframe is :

```
id  number  name    time    method  level
121 567     XYZ     24      run     150
234 679     ABC     56      floor   120
121 567     XYZ     26      walk    150
578 865     EFG     89      fly     430
965 685     MNO     40      cry     278
578 865     MNO     67      fly     430
```

Required Output

```
id  number  name    time    method  level
121 567     1       2       2       1
234 679     1       1       1       1
578 865     2       2       1       1
965 685     1       1       1       1
```

So, what I want in my output is number of unique elements for each groupby(["id", "number")] result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby.agg` with `nunique`:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'number']).agg(pd.Series.nunique)
Out: 
            name  time  method  level
id  number                           
121 567        1     2       2      1
234 679        1     1       1      1
578 865        2     2       1      1
965 685        1     1       1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `groupby-apply` and then an `apply` on each series to only count the unique values:

```
df.groupby(['id','number'])['name', 'time', 'method', 'level']\
    .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y.drop_duplicates().count()))\
    .reset_index([0,1])

# Output:

    id  number  name  time  method  level
0  121     567     1     2       2      1
1  234     679     1     1       1      1
2  578     865     2     2       1      1
3  965     685     1     1       1      1
```

I hope this helps.